# Angular/Typescript: declare return type of lambda passed to "find"

Tags: angular, typescript, lambda, strong-typing

So, I am following a training course and have an Angular service:

```
import {Exercise} from "./exercise.model";

export class TrainingService{
  private availableExercises: Exercise[] = [
    { id: 'crunches', name: 'Crunches', duration: 30, calories: 8 },
    { id: 'touch-toes', name: 'Touch Toes', duration: 180, calories: 15 },
    { id: 'side-lunges', name: 'Side Lunges', duration: 120, calories: 18 },
    { id: 'burpees', name: 'Burpees', duration: 60, calories: 8 }
  ];

  private currentExercise: Exercise | null = null;

  getAvailableExercises() : Exercise[] {
    return this.availableExercises.slice();   //// slice() returns a copy (new object), not a reference
  }

  startExercise(exerciseId: string) : void {
    this.currentExercise = this.availableExercises.find( (exercise: Exercise) : Exercise | null => 
        {exercise.id === exerciseId});
  }

}
```

I just added `startExercise)()` and get an error. I can, of course, recode it not to use `find()`, but would prefer to know what is happening here.  Coming from a strongly typed language background, I have enforced type checking.

The specific error is

```
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Exercise | null'.

18     this.currentExercise = this.availableExercises.find( (exercise: Exercise) : Exercise | null => {exercise.id === exerciseId});
       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: src/app/training/training.service.ts:18:81 - error TS2355: A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return a value.

18     this.currentExercise = this.availableExercises.find( (exercise: Exercise) : Exercise | null => {exercise.id === exerciseId});
```

How do I fix that code?

Comment: .find() will return undefined if matching is not found so you are getting undefined error (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find). You can provide type explicitly if you are 100% sure find() will return single item like <Exercise>this.availableExercises.find().....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typescript compiler knows the array AvailableExercises is of type Exercise[], so you actually dont have to define the (exercise: Exercise) : Exercise | null again as type Exercise.

Just putting:

```
this.currentExercise = this.availableExercises.find(exercise => exercise.id === exerciseId);
```

Should already be working. You can check if it found anything as array.find will return the first element where the predicate is true and undefined otherwise. So

```
if (!this.currentExercise) {
   // Here some error or your own idea
}
```

---

Op here, apologies for editing the answer, but I can't really code format in commants.

1. `private currentExercise: Exercise | undefined;`
2. `this.currentExercise = this.availableExercises.find( (exercise: Exercise)  => {exercise.id === exerciseId});` and it works

Comment: Alas, it still gives an error :-(  `error TS2322: Type 'Exercise | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Exercise | null'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Exercise | null'.`

Comment: Don't bother to `private currentExercise: Exercise | null = null;`, just `private currentExercise: Exercise;` is enough :)

Comment: Oh, actually I already edited my answer to explain this. array.find will return either an element of Exercise or undefined if none found, so you could change null to undefined.

Comment: And yes, what @Pilpo says is what I would do as well. But the reason behind the error is as explained, array.find returns either your type or undefined :).

Comment: @Pipo Because of strng type checking ,that gievs `TS2564: Property 'currentExercise' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.` But, nvm, as @sdev95 has answered it